# Проблема в открытии файла внутри функции, вылетает консоль

Tags: c++, c

Это модуль, как только перестаю открывать файл внутри главного модуля консоль крашится, хочу написать функцию открытия файла и его проверки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "funcv.h"
void openr(FILE *a, char z[10] )
{
using namespace std;
a=fopen(z,"r+");
if(a)
goto zzz;
else
{
while(!a)
{
cout<<"Введите название файла еще раз:";
gets(z);
a=fopen(z, "r+");
}
goto zzz;
}
zzz: cout<<"Успешно открыто"<<endl;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ужасно! Не используйте `goto` без надобности. В идеале - никогда!
Вот эта функция без `goto`

```
void openr(FILE *a, char z[10] )
{
    a=fopen(z,"r+");
    while(!a)
    { 
        cout<<"Введите название файла еще раз:";
        gets(z);
        a=fopen(z, "r+");
    }
    cout<<"Успешно открыто"<<endl;
}
```

Из формулировки вопроса с трудом понятна проблема.
Но скорее всего дело в том, что вы передаете в функцию указатель на файл по значению. После того как в функции вы открываете файл, указатель на открытый файл сохраняется в **локальной** переменной `a=fopen(z,"r+");` и его значение никак не попадает  в вызывающий код, например в `main()`. И пытаясь в `main()` что-то прочитать из файла по указателю, который не указывает на открытый файл, происходит ошибка.
В данном случае нужно возвращать указатель на файл либо передавать в функцию указатель на файл по ссылке:

```
FILE* openr( const char* name ){} // возвращает указатель на открытый файл
main()
{ 
  FILE* myfile = openr("myfile.txt");
}

// ---------------------------------

void openr(FILE& *f, const char* name ){} // получает указатель по ссылке
main()
{ 
  FILE* myfile = NULL;
  openr( myfile, "myfile.txt"); // передача по ссылке, чтобы изменилось значение в main()
}
```

Comment: спасибо, я бы скинул полный код. но он довольно длинный, суть в том, что я в файл ввожу массив структур и вот если я не открываю файл в главном модуле, то после ввода первого элемента массива консоль крашится.

Comment: ну правильно. вы открыли файл в функции и указатель на файл не вернули туда, откуда функция вызывалась. В итоге пытаетесь по указателю, кот указывает в никуда, вывести в файл информацию. Вот и крах.

Comment: понял, изменил код, спасибо

Comment: Если ответ подошел - нажмите галочку "принять" слева от ответа

Answer (score 0):

Вот вчерашний код, который я вам писал, но с вашей функцией:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
};

FILE* openr( char* name ) // возвращает указатель на открытый файл
{
    FILE* fd = fopen(name, "rb");
    while(!fd)
    { 
        cout<<"Введите название файла еще раз:"<<endl;
        gets(name);
        fd = fopen( name, "rb");
    }
    return fd;
} 

int main()
{
  FILE *fd;
  char name[256] = "f001.bin";
  int size = 3;
  A mass[size] = {
      { 1, 2, 'a'},
      { 3, 4, 'b'},
      { 5, 6, 'c'}
  };
  
  A mass1[size];
  
  fd = fopen(name, "wb");
  fwrite(mass, sizeof(mass[0]), size, fd);
  fclose(fd);
  
  fd = openr(name);
  fread(mass1, sizeof(mass1[0]), size, fd);
  fclose(fd);
  
  for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
      cout<< mass1[i].a << " " << mass1[i].b << " " << mass1[i].c << "\n";
  }
  
}
```

`gets` лучше не использовать.
Вместо нее используйте `getline` https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline